# WebClient problem with URL which ends with a period

Tags: c#, url, webclient

I'm running the following code;

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string page = wc.DownloadString(URL);
    ...
}
```

To access the URL of a share price website, http://www.shareprice.co.uk

If you append a company's symbol name onto the end of the URL, then a page is returned which I parse to get the latest price info etc.

e.g.

http://www.shareprice.co.uk/VOD

http://www.shareprice.co.uk/TW.

Now, my problem is that some symbols end in periods, as in the second example there. For some unknown reason, the code above has a problem retrieving these sorts of URLs.

There is no run-time error, but a page is returned back which reports "Symbol could not be found" from the website itself, indicating that something is happening to the period on the end of the URL in between the call to DownloadString and the actual HTTP request.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this, and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you control http://www.shareprice.co.uk, or is this a 3rd party site?

Comment: If it's 3rd party, have you checked their documentation on how to handle periods in your URL?

Comment: It's a 3rd party site, I've no association with them at all - this is just a small hobby project I'm working on.

I should probably have clarified, if you type an address with a period on the end into a browser, it works fine. Hence the question on here, as I presume it must be a .NET issue.

Comment: Did you try the same url without the .?  They may do something client side when you go via a browser.

You could try url encoding the url string.  I saw some other people having similar problems on various platforms when I asked google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you found a bug in WebClient/WebRequest, though perhaps Microsoft put that in intentionally, who knows.  Nonetheless, when you pass in TW., the URI class is translating that to TW without the period.  Since WebClient/WebRequest parse strings into URI, your . is disappearing in that world.

You may have to use TcpClient to get around this and roll your own web client.  Any variation of this:

```
TcpClient oClient = new TcpClient("www.shareprice.co.uk", 80);

NetworkStream ns = oClient.GetStream();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
sw.Write(
   string.Format( 
      "GET /{0} HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: {1}\r\nHost: www.shareprice.co.uk\r\n\r\n",
           "TW.", 
           "MyTCPClient"  )
);                    
sw.Flush();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (true)
{
    int i = ns.ReadByte(); // Inefficient but more reliable 
    if (i == -1) break;  // Other side has closed socket 
    sb.Append( (char) i );   // Accrue 'c' to save page data 
}

oClient.Close();
```

This will give you a 302 redirect, so just parse out the 'Location:' and execute the above again with the new location.

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
> Date: Wed, 11 Nov 2009 19:29:27 GMT
> Server: lighttpd
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.7
> Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
> Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
> Pragma: no-cache
> Location: /TW./TAYLOR-WIMPEY-PLC
> Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 0
> Set-Cookie: SSID=668d5d0023e9885e1ef3762ef5e44033; path=/
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> Connection: close
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a slash to the end, after the period.  Your normal web browser will do that for you, and the WebClient class isn't that smart.

```
http://www.shareprice.co.uk/TW./
```

This worked for me as well when I typed it into the browser.

**Edit - added**

The following all also worked in the browser

```
http://www.shareprice.co.uk/TW
```

and

http://www.shareprice.co.uk/TW/

so it looks like you should be able to just check to see if the last character is a period, and remove it.

Comment: However it does not seem to work in WebClient or WebRequest.  Both of these classes convert strings to Uri.  When a Uri is handed that TW. url, it seems to remove the period.  Presumably it believes you intended to complete the file extension, however it wasn't completed, so it just cuts it off.

Answer (score 0):

use URL encoding...it will turn the "." into %2E

Comment: At first glance, one would think this would work, but it does not seem to.

Comment: Are you using Fiddler to trace the calls?  Might be a good idea.  When you can see how the raw request looks, it sometimes offers more clues than just plain old debugging does.

Answer (score 0):

To address a single period (.) at the end of a URL use the following:

```
<system.web>
             <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" /> 
</system.web>
```

To address two periods (..) or other denied sequences, see the following article:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/denyUrlSequences

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space after the period, when parsing the space will be removed but the period will stay there.