# Is it possible to create a Uri that ends with a period?

Tags: c#, uri

I'm currently creating a web scraper and have run into a bit of a snag. Due to poor file management on the website's part, some of the files uploaded by users end in a period:

```
//The file should have been 123.jpg,
// but the uploader/website did something incorrectly.
string path = "www.example.com/files/123.";
```

When using a `WebClient` or an `HttpWebRequest`, you pass the location of the request, which eventually is turned into a `Uri`. The problem arises when the `Uri` is created, because it automatically corrects any "errors" that the string might have. This removes the trailing period in my request and turns it into `www.example.com/files/123`

I did browse SO and came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716667/webclient-problem-with-url-which-ends-with-a-period), however wasn't completely satisfied with having to use a `TcpClient` as a workaround. Is there any way to adjust the creation of the Uri so as to include the trailing period, or am I stuck with having to use a `TcpClient`?

Comment: check this question, it's similar to your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716667/webclient-problem-with-url-which-ends-with-a-period

regarding the ability to write URLs that ends with periods, YES you can. but it's AWFUL :0)

Comment: @MohammedElSayed Yep, that's the same question I ran into when I was searching for an answer. It's a really really ugly workaround and was hoping something changed since the 2 and a half years when it was asked. :(

Comment: Have you tried to use `HttpClient` instead?

Comment: @user854301 That's a .NET 4.5 class, correct? I currently have 4.0, so I have not tried that. Looking at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes me think it has the same underlying issue since it makes use of `Uri`, which is where this problem stems from.

Comment: It's also worth seeing if thy fixed the bug in `Uri` with 4.5, I suppose.